# Is there a java cache library that stores data in database instead of in-memory?

Tags: java, caching

We need to build a replicated cache to cache third party application data to have better performance. The data includes strings (messages) and images (profile pics). The third party application does not support webhooks or any other api's to keep the data in sync. We need to build an auto-refresh strategy that implements some sort of refresh-ahead.

Most of the cache libraries including google's guava, ehcache, cache2k etc cache data in-memory. There are a few problems that we foresee if with in-memory replicated cache

1. When the number of application servers scale up, keeping the same copy of the cached data across servers becomes a challenge as we implement auto-refresh (or refresh-ahead). It is much simplified if there is one copy of the cached data.
2. Re-building the cache if the server crashes needs to be take care off.
3. Synchronization of data across app servers would be difficult when implement write-through or write behind.
4. Number of third party api calls reduce if there is one copy of the data across servers.
5. Amount of data that could be cached would not have to be limited/restricted since it would be outside the jvm's memory.

Since the database/file would be closer to the app server, the performance would be better as compared to third party servers. Note, we already have a database (Oracle) in our stack, hence we would not want to introduce another database just for this.

The cache library needs to support concurrent writes from multiple processes. Is there a java library that supports above requirements?

Thanks.

Comment: This article might be helpful: [Extending Guava caches to overflow to disk](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/12/extending-guava-caches-to-overflow-to-disk.html)

Comment: @Kizivat - thanks for the link but it seems that the CacheLoader is called only on cache miss which means guava internally maintains an in-memory data structure to hold cached entries. I am looking for something that does not have any in-memory footprint. Every time the application calls the cache it should hit the database or file. Can guava be configured for such a case?

Answer (score 0):

We had similar requirement and we went ahead with adaptation of MongoDB as nosql database.

It really depends on the type of application but with Microservices and REST/Json adaptation use of mongodb might be your right choice. MongoDB with proper configuration and replicset is very robust & scalable solution to tackle with performance of millions of records with properly indexed lookup fields.

The way MongoDB is designed is it uses most of the memory of the server on which it is deployed and keep the data in memory, which makes it as good as cache. From application point of view it is your in-sync data - which is completely scalable and uses the high performance disks like SSDs for data retrieval for the persisted data.

Also there are many supported features like expiry etc on documents
, which makes it very easy to manage and purge the cache to control the space.

Your all application servers can connect to mongo replica set and you can enable reads from secondary mongo server as well to get best of the mongo db replica set.

Other options to consider are Apache cassandra and other nosql solutions.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Good suggestion but I forgot to mention one caveat - we already have Oracle in our stack. Updated the description now. Ideal would be to reuse the same for keeping this data. I am trying to understand if the out-of-the-box java libraries such a requirement.

Comment: Hi Andy, I see what you mean. Not used oracle for such requirement of cachin, however I can understand that introducing new component is quite a tedious task in the application stack. I am not aware/sure, if any java lib can do this without underlying db support. You can think of having hybrid model, which many organisation follow like Oracle for relational database and other nosql solution for transient data.